# jQuery Ajax Cross Domain Mixed Content. How is this happening?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess, https

I am working on a Chrome Extension that will run on a 3rd party website. On page load it will make an API call to the 3rd party API and display some of the API information on the page.

## Important bits of info

1. The extension will be running on `https://app.example.com`.
2. The API endpoints are under `https://api.example.com`.
3. I cannot modify the code or server configurations for either of the above.

Since my browser extension runs as if it were on the page it obviously introduces cross-domain ajax issues so to get around this I have put together a PHP script on `https://forward.example.com`. I can modify the code and server configuration for this.

### `https://forward.example.com`

Purpose: To accept requests from any domain, and forward the request to the domain specified in the `X-Destination-Url` header. It should also respond back to the original request with the headers and content of the `X-Destination-Url` request.

#### `forward.php`

I know this is messy, but I just threw it together in a couple of minutes.

```
$headers = getallheaders();
$destinationKey = 'X-Destination-Url';
$destination = null;
$removeHeaders = array('Origin', 'X-Destination-Url', 'Referer');
if (array_key_exists($destinationKey, $headers)) {
    $destination = $headers[$destinationKey];
    unset($headers[destinationKey]);
}
foreach ($removeHeaders as $h) {
    unset($headers[$h]);
}
$authTokenKey = 'X-Destination-Auth-Token';
$authToken = null;
if (array_key_exists($authTokenKey, $headers)) {
    $authToken = $headers[$authTokenKey];
    unset($headers[$authTokenKey]);
    $headers['X-Auth-Token'] = $authToken;
}
if ($destination === null) {
    die('Invalid X-Destination-Url');
}

$preparedHeaders = array();
foreach ($headers as $k => $v) {
    $preparedHeaders[] = "{$k}:{$v}";
}

$responseHeaders = array();

function handleHeaderLine($ch, $headerLine)
{
    global $responseHeaders;
    $responseHeaders[] = $headerLine;
    return strlen($headerLine);
}    

$ch = curl_init();

// Note that at this point $destination == 'https://api.example.com'
$opts = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $destination,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION => 'handleHeaderLine',
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'],
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $preparedHeaders,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
);

curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);

$resp = curl_exec($ch);

foreach ($responseHeaders as $header) {
    header($header);
}

echo $resp;
die;
```

#### `.htaccess`

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, X-Auth-Token, X-Destination-Url, X-Destination-Auth-Token"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

### Chrome Extension

The Chrome Extension just runs as javascript on-page.

This is the bit of code that interacts with the above.

```
$.get({
    async: true,
    url: 'https://forward.example.com/forward.php',
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Destination-Auth-Token', 'api-key ' + self.apiKey);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Destination-Url', 'https://api.example.com');
    },
    success: function (d) {
        console.log(d);
    }
});
```

When the above runs, Chrome spits out the following error...

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://app.example.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://api.example.com'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

## Finally...

How on earth has `https://api.example.com` been changed to `http://api.example.com`?

At the point that `forward.php` makes the `curl` request to `X-Destination-Url` it is using the correct `https` url, and it is set up to accept any SSL Certificate, so I'm quite confused as to how this is happening.

Can anyone give me some insight into what's going on here?

Comment: Why would the browser make an XMLHttpRequest for the API URL in the first place - when you say you replaced that by your forward script URL? Does the API response contain any scripts that cause further requests or something like that? Otherwise, I don’t see how this could happen unless you are still making an explicit AJAX request to the API URL somewhere in your code.

Comment: @CBroe I have no idea. If I `die` at the top of my PHP script the error doesn't occur. Similarly if I comment out the JS the error doesn't occur. The API response should just be a JSON array.

Comment: Have you _verified_ that $destination contains the HTTPS API URL? And have you checked what the API response contains?

Comment: `$destination` is the correct value when the `curl` request is made. After checking the actual response I've just noticed that I'm getting a 301 response. Adding `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true` to my curl options removes that. But I am now getting `net::ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING`. Time to do some more digging.